# Finding an up to date website with detailed information on viruses

Tags: virus, threat-modeling

Is there a website with the ability to search through viruses that will return detailed information on them?  I can't seem to find one and I'm tired of only getting forums when I search for a specific virus on Google.  I want to be able to look up a particular virus and read information about what that particular virus does/tries to do.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are interested in something similar to the [National Vulnerability Database (NVD)](http://nvd.nist.gov/), except for malware.  I am not sure such a thing exists, but here are some similar repositories:

- http://home.mcafee.com/virusinfo/
- http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/Threat/Views.aspx
- http://www.virustotal.com/search.html
- http://about-threats.trendmicro.com/threatencyclopedia.aspx?language=us&tab=malware
- http://www.f-secure.com/en/web/labs_global/threats/descriptions
- http://www.sophos.com/en-us/threat-center/threat-analyses/viruses-and-spyware.aspx

Perhaps it would be a good project to stand up a site that  queries all of these repos and provides results from all of them in one place.